# How to fetch value of dynamically created textbox in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp

I am creating a social networking site and I am facing one problem.

I am fetching records from database and with each record I want to add one button so that I can change that record using that text box.

But when I am updating record using that text box, it is getting value of the first text box only. If I am updating `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` etc record then it is getting value of first text box.

So please help me how can I get value of each and every text box - not just from the first one.

Thanks in advance.

Below is my code:

```
<%
Statement st1;
         ResultSet rs1;
         Connection con;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dfmc","root","93Pb3gaNv0");
String sql1="select * from user_table LIMIT 5";
            st1 = con.createStatement();
            rs1=st1.executeQuery(sql1);
            String id=null,name=null;
while(rs1.next()){
                id=rs1.getString("id");
                name=rs1.getString("first_name");
                %>
<div><input type="text" name="txt" id="name" />
<input type="button" name="btn" value="Rating" onclick="loadXMLDoc(<%=id%>)">
                    <p id="showname"><%=name%></p>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(iid){
var idd=iid;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {





document.getElementById("showname").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 

    }
}
var name;
name = document.getElementById("name").value;
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'insert_rating?name='+name+'&id='+idd+'', true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: where your while loop is closed

Comment: As an aside - don't use scriptlets in your JSPs, keep them just for displaying the view.

Comment: while loop ending in last

Comment: @nadeemahmad the id of the name field should be unique

Comment: how can it be unique please tell me

Comment: when records come from database then textbox is created with same id...but i want unique id for that textbox..how can i do this..i dont know

Comment: @nadeemahmad you can do `<input type="text" name="txt" id="name<%=id%>" />` then do `name = document.getElementById("name"+idd).value;`.Also close the while loop before script tag

Comment: Before `<script type="text/javascript">` you should have `<% }//end while %>`

Comment: it is showing error in this line...<input type="text" name="txt" id="name<%=id%>" />..... The error is .. Bad value  "name  " for attribute "id" on element "input": An ID must not contain whitespace

Comment: I'd seriously recommend that, rather that persisting with this messy (and VERY outdated) mix of three languages (which doesn't currently compile anyway) that you stop and start again doing it properly - it'll save you a lot of pain and work in the long run.  You might want to read this: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WhyNotUseScriptlets

Comment: then what should i do now...  Fluffmeister General

Comment: @nadeemahmad use browser inspect element to check which input field contain space.Also i agree with Fluffmeister

Comment: thank u sooooooooo much bro ... singhakash ...it works

Comment: And thanx Fluffmeister  for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, but I could easily get javascript dynamic text box value on servlet, by using request.getParameterValues("DynamicTextBox");

## client side code:

```
$("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
        var values = "";
        $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
            values += $(this).val() + "\n";
        });
        alert(values);

    });

});
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' +
            '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />'
}
```

## server side code (servlet):

```
String[] duration= request.getParameterValues("DynamicTextBox");
for (String string : duration) {
    System.out.println("Duration1=="+string);
}
```